# Delphi xe6 & Android types

Tags: android, delphi, generics, delphi-xe6

As per android SDK Collection & List is generic. Why in Delphi xe6 or xe5 they can't be use as generic? How can I use both of them as generic?

Comment: Could you perhaps show us how you are consuming these Java types from your Delphi code so we have more context.

Comment: var flist : JList<JString>;

Comment: @Shariful: what about that is not Generic to you?

Comment: I can't use them as generic although Collection is generic in java so why not in Delphi